# Dot Directory not copied to Docker Volume nor commited to Docker IMage

Tags: docker, gradle

I came across this oddity (at least new for me). The basic idea is to have a Gradle build image or volume with cached dependencies for offline builds. Therefore, when online I do

```
docker run -it --rm --name gradle -v gradle:/home/gradle -v ./app:/home/gradle/app -u gradle gradle:jdk17 bash
cd app && gradle build
```

Now `/home/gradle/.gradle` contains the expected caches etc.

However, while keeping the first container up, I start a second container

```
    docker run -it --rm -v gradle:/home/gradle -u gradle gradle:jdk17 bash
```

and `/home/gradle/.gradle` is empty. If I'd be to copy `.gradle/` to `_gradle/` on the first container, it appears (as expected) on the Docker volume and therefore in the second container.

Docker committing the first container and checking a derived container in the same way shows the same result: nothing in `.gradle/`.

I was wondering how that happens. I'm using Docker Desktop 4.26.1 with Docker Engine 24.0.7 on a Mac (I saw the same behaviour on a Linux box though). Am I missing something fundamental like configuring directories that are not synced across images and not committed to Docker images?

Comment: Committing an image is essentially never a best practice.  If the volume mount is happening successfully, the committed image will not contain the content from the mounted volumes.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind on */home/gradle/.gradle* instead (replacing `-v gradle:/home/gradle` with `-v gradle:/home/gradle/.gradle`) might solve your problem and you will have the cache content shared on both containers.

When volumes are bound, a link is created between a path on the container with the Docker volume, and when the container's path is updated (adding or deleting files, including folders), this change is reflected on the volume. However, this link is just valid for the bound path and not for other paths inside the container when the binding occurs, even when these paths are related on subdirectories of the bound path. This is why creating the `_gradle` changes the volume and also affects the other container: you are modifying the bound path `/home/gradle` by adding the `_gradle` folder to it; but that doesn't happen for `/home/gradle/.gradle`, because you have no bind link with associated with this path. Please be aware that in this scenario, any alterations made to the `_gradle` directory, such as adding or deleting files, will directly impact the associated volume. This occurs because the operating system recognizes the connection between `_gradle` and the volume, thus considering any changes to `_gradle` as applicable to the volume.

**Recommendation:**

To mitigate the issue highlighted in this post, I recommend exclusively binding empty folders (or folders that do not exist, making Docker create them) onto a Docker volume. This practice avoids having subdirectories without links with the volumes.